# QT баги после стилизации QSlider

Tags: qt, qslider

После того как накинул стили для QSlider нельзя взять ползунок и перетащить на необходимый цвет, приходится нажимать на линию где он может проходить и только в таком случае будет происходить перемещение

Применённые стили:

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
     height: 8px; /* по умолчанию бороздка расширяется до размеров ползунка. задав высоту она принимает фиксированный размер */
    background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255), stop:0.166 rgba(255, 255, 0, 255), stop:0.333 rgba(0, 255, 0, 255), stop:0.5 rgba(0, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.666 rgba(0, 0, 255, 255), stop:0.833 rgba(255, 0, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255));
 }

 QSlider::handle:horizontal {
     background: white;
     border: 1px #5c5c5c;
     width: 12px;
     margin: 14px 0; /* рукоятка располагается по умолчанию в прямоугольнике содержимого бороздки. Расширяется наружу от бороздки */
     border-radius: 3px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на [box model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нас интересует magin. Как раз задав его в 14px, вы и убрали возможность взаимодействовать с ползунком. Но можно сделать так:

```
 QSlider::handle:horizontal {
     background: white;
     border: 1px #5c5c5c;
     width: 12px;
     margin: -12px 0; /* <--- */
     border-radius: 3px;
 }
```

См. к примеру [статью](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/margin) про отрицательные значения margin